# Lazy Loading results in ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I implement lazy loading and result into this error. I have seen many post and none of them are giving the solution.

How to reproduce:

1. Go to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxmpj8
2. Click on orders tab
3. Click Test

Expected: It opens Test component
Actual: It results into **"Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:" error**

I am trying to lazy load the orders module which has two components orders and test. The orders route is working fine but the test component route throws error.

The application is at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxmpj8

At orders-routing.module.ts the routes are defined as below:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OrdersComponent,

    children: [
      { path: 'test', component: TestComponent
  }]
  }
];
```

The routes at app-routing.module.ts are defined as below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule)
  },
  {
   path: 'orders',

   // Tried this also
   // loadChildren:  './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

In orders.component.ts file I have an entry

```
<button routerLink="/test">Test</button>
```

Clicking this result into error

**ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'**

Comment: Did you try to restart the server (run `ng serve`) again?

Comment: yes, no luck. Have refresh npm cache, run npm install

Comment: @Ningomba  i know what you are wroing but i don't uderstand what do you want? if click test the user where have to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. Because your test component is setup as a child route, you need a module-level `<router-outlet>` so that the Angular router knows where to render your test component.
2. On your "test" button, you need to specify the entire route (including `/orders`).

I forked your stackblitz so you can see it working here => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxmpj8-q9xzzv

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

First the routerLink should be a relative path, otherwise it will go to the root of the app, and there is no `/test` path defined at the app routes.
A relative path in a routerLink is relative to the current `router-outlet` the `routerLink` is defined in.

Second, the `orders.component.html` also needs a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, otherwise the test component won't be placed anywhere.

Something like this:

```
<button routerLink="test">Test</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxmpj8-vc6bar?file=src/app/orders/orders.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `routerLink="/orders/test"` instead of just `routerLink="/test"`.
Also you need to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the orders.component.html to show the testComponent's view.

Change in `orders.component.html`

```
     <p>
      orders works!
    </p>

    <button routerLink="/orders/test">Test</button>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: @Ningomba checkout the solution.

Comment: @Ningomba glad was able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<button routerLink="/orders">Test</button>
```

and after modify this in order-routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OrdersComponent
  }
]
  }
];
```